# Accessing Blob content from within ARM Template for API Management API GraphQL Schema

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management, azure-rm-template

The GraphQL schema content is large so would like to store in blob container and access it from API Management ARM Template to obtain its contents.
I already store linked templates in same area and have enough detail to compose the URI with SAS Token .
The issue I have is getting the contents from the blob and loading them into a string variable.  Whatever I try I cannot access the contents.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "ApimServiceName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "appInsightsName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocation" : {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "_artifactsLocationSasToken" :{
        "type": "string"
    },
    "_buildNumber" :{
        "type": "string"
    },
    "KeyvaultName": {
         "type": "string"
    }
},
"variables": {
    "linkedSchemas": {
        "schemauri": "[concat(parameters('_artifactsLocation'), parameters('_buildNumber'), '/sample-graphql-schema.graphql',parameters('_artifactsLocationSasToken'))]"
    }
},
"resources": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('ApimServiceName'), '/graphql-sample')]",
        "dependsOn": [],
        "properties": {
            "description": "",
            "authenticationSettings": {
                "subscriptionKeyRequired": false
            },
            "subscriptionKeyParameterNames": {
                "header": "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",
                "query": "subscription-key"
            },
            "type": "graphql",
            "apiRevision": "1",
            "subscriptionRequired": true,
            "displayName": "GraphQL API",
            "serviceUrl": "https://emea.sample.com/api/graphql",
            "path": "graphql-sample",
            "protocols": [
                "http",
                "https"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "apiVersion": "2021-08-01",
        "type": "Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('ApimServiceName'), '/graphql-sample/graphql')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis', parameters('ApimServiceName'), 'graphql-sample')]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.ms-azure-apim.graphql.schema",
            "document": {
                "value": "[concat('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8;base64,', base64(variables('linkedSchemas').schemauri))]"
            }
        }
    }, etc...
```

Can anyone share how to obtain the contents of the blob?  Perhaps I need to find a different way to access the blob.  All the code does as it stands is turn the URI itself into base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ARM Templates on their own do does not support fetching values from a URL as far as I know. But APIM Templates do support passing in values, which the service can fetch contents for.

For this, you don't need the `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis/schemas` sub-resource, instead the `Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/apis` resource itself has properties that you need to set.

- `format` should be set to `graphql-link`
- `value` should be set to the URL of your GraphQL Schema File including the SAS Token

Refer the [reference doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.apimanagement/service/apis?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template) for more information.

Comment: I need to investigate further, initially I am receiving a parsing error obtaining the API declaration.   I'll revert when I have something working. This appears to be the right means.